# How do I retrieve ethereum mistakenly sent to a wallet address?

Tags: solidity, smart-contract-wallets

Following the advice of a web3 developer, I did the following:

1. I created a smart contract(https://hastebin.com/share/uyuvolavoh.php) using remix.re and deposited 0,69 ETH to it.
2. I then clicked the start function in the smart contract and discovered that all the ETH on the contract address got transferred to the wallet address https://etherscan.io/address/0x5b9ecba05be58d3dbab5e1981c8669259dec7ad4#internaltx.

The idea was to create an arbitrage trading bot, but the reality was a one time transfer from the contract address to the wallet address.

Now is there anything I can do to retrieve this ETH?

Comment: No, it's a common scam

Comment: I just fell for this scam did you get anything?

Comment: 0x5B9ecBA05BE58D3dBaB5E1981C8669259deC7AD4 this is the scam add. it got me twive before i noticed it. i also messageed this person but got no response if anyone finds a way to get the funds back or wants to talk about this im on telegram t.me/Aza19901990